# What are integer solutions to $x^2+7=y^3$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves

> **Question:** What are the integer solutions to$$x^2+7=y^3\tag1$$

Through Wolfram Alpha, there seems to be only two solutions. Namely, $$\begin{align*} & (x,y)=(1,2)\\ & (x,y)=(181,32)\end{align*}\tag2$$
So I'm wondering about how would you find those solutions. And is there a way to use some sort of transformation to make $(1)$ into a more recognizable form.

And furthermore, is there a formula to determine other type solutions similar to what you already have?

Comment: Are you sure about this? Plugging (2,1) in, we get $2^2 +7 = 1^3$. I think you might mean (1,2).

Comment: It's the opposite , 1,2

Comment: Oops, yes. Thank you for that note. It's fixed now.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordell_curve (note that because of the way yours is written, it actually corresponds to $n=-7$ by Wikipedia's notation, not $n=7$.)

Comment: @DietrichBurde This is $x^2+k=y^3$

Comment: @Frank You can interchange $x$ and $y$ (or rename it), this does not matter.

Comment: @DietrichBurde It doesn't?

Comment: @Frank Not at all.  If $x^2+k=y^3$ then $x^2=y^3-k$; now just swap variables with, e.g., $y'=x$ and $x'=y$ to get $y'^2=x'^3-k$, which is exactly the other given equation.

Answer (score 3):

According to
this link in
the Wikipedia article
on the Mordell curve,
your solutions are
the only ones:

http://tnt.math.se.tmu.ac.jp/simath/MORDELL/MORDELL-

That file claims
to have all solutions
for 
$|x^2-y^3| 
\le 10000
$.

I also recommend this presentation,
which was found by
a Google search for
"mordell equation":

http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/ross2008/mordell.pdf